# How to use the Watson Conversation inside iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, watson-conversation

I am going to update my customised sample based on [Build a home assistant mobile application with Watson and IoT Platform services](http://Build%20a%20home%20assistant%20mobile%20application%20with%20Watson%20and%20IoT%20Platform%20services)

**In this code I get the message:**

*Can not convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'InputData?'*

How to solve this problem?
Inside the [documentation of developer cloud/conversation/api](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message) I can find the definition of **InputData**, but **NO** sample how to realize this in Swift iOS?

```
    // Based on API Changes
    // ====================
    // Incorrect argument label in call (have 'text:context:', expected 'input:context:')
    // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'InputData?'
    let request = MessageRequest(input: text, context: self.context)
    self.conversation?.message(workspaceID: Credentials.ConversationWorkspaceID,
                               request: request,
                               failure: failure) {
                                response in
                                print(response.output.text)
                                self.didReceiveConversationResponse(response.output.text)
                                self.context = response.context
                                // issue command based on intents and entities
                                // Additional Properties:
                                // response.context.json -> response.context.additionalProperties
                                print("appl_action: \(response.context.additionalProperties["appl_action"])")
                                self.issueCommand(intents: response.intents, entities: response.entities)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` parameter of the `MessageRequest` constructor takes an `InputData` object, which is easy to construct from a text string.  Try

```
let input = InputData(text: text)
let request = MessageRequest(input: input, context: self.context)
self.conversation?.message(workspaceID: Credentials.ConversationWorkspaceID,
                           request: request,
                           failure: failure) {
```

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks but after fixing this now I have a other problem with "framework not found RestKit". Regards, Thomas

Comment: If you are using the latest release of the Watson Swift SDK, it no longer builds RestKit as a separate framework, but instead links it directly into each service.  So you should be able to just remove the RestKit framework from your project.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am not sure this 

Can you pls take a look here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277430/how-is-the-restkit-related-to-the-new-watson-conversation-sdk-linker-error